# Distributing values evenly within zones when converting polygon to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-conversion

I'm trying to convert a (traffic analysis zone) TAZ polygon to raster so that the population values are evenly distributed within each zone.

So far, when converting the TAZ polygon, the same population value is included in each of the hundreds of cells that make up a zone.

I'm using ArcEditor/Spatial Analyst.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a statistics on the raster to determine the cell count per zone, then do a reclassification by zone to give the adjusted population value - i.e. original population / # of cells.